# how to display a numpy array with pyglet?

Tags: python, numpy, pyglet

I have a label matrix with dimension (100*100), stored as a numpy array, and I would like to display the matrix with pyglet.

My original idea is to use this matrix to form a new pyglet image using function pyglet.image.ImageData(). It requres a buffer of the imagedata as an input, however I have no idea how to get a right formated buffer from the numpy array.

Any one have any idea?

ps. my current solution:

```
3d_label = numpy.empty([100,100,3])
3d_label[:,:,0] = label * 255            # value range of label is [0,1]
3d_label[:,:,1] = label * 255
3d_label[:,:,2] = label * 255
image_data = ctypes.string_at(id(3d_label.tostring())+20, 100*100*3)
image = pyglet.image.ImageData(100, 100, 'RGB', image_data, -100*3)
```

Any better way to construct a [100*100*3] matrix from 3 [100*100] matrix with numpy?

Comment: you should also consider glumpy for displaying numpy arrays

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are looking for is `np.dstack` (or more generally, `np.concatenate`):

```
label255=label*255
label3=numpy.dstack((label255,label255,label255))
```

This shows `dstack` produces the same array (`label3`) as your construction for `label_3d`:

```
import numpy as np

label=np.random.random((100,100))
label255=label*255
label3=np.dstack((label255,label255,label255))

label_3d = np.empty([100,100,3])
label_3d[:,:,0] = label * 255            # value range of label is [0,1]
label_3d[:,:,1] = label * 255
label_3d[:,:,2] = label * 255
print(np.all(label3==label_3d))
# True
```

PS. I'm not sure, but have you tried using `label3.data` instead of `ctypes.string_at(id(label3.tostring())+20, 100*100*3)` ?

Comment: +1 for ``label3.data``, which is more efficient than building a string.

Comment: label3.data.__str__() can replace ctypes.string_at(id(label3.tostring())+20, 100*100*3), but label3.data can not

Answer (score 1):

You can get the memory representation of your array with `3d_label.tostring()`.

The `tostring()` method allows you to change the memory ordering of the elements:

```
Parameters
----------
order : {'C', 'F', None}, optional
    Order of the data for multidimensional arrays:
    C, Fortran, or the same as for the original array.
```

PS: The `3d_label.data` of ~unutbu requires less memory, since no string is constructed.  However, it does not allow you to change the order in which the elements are output.